# Type of Linux/Unix I/O

Tags: linux, unix, io, buffered, unbuffered

i have to make a presentation about **Linux/Unix I/O: File I/O,Standard I/O, buffered/unbuffered I/O and formatted/unformatted I/O**.

i'm not sure how to order these kinds of I/O to make sense.

here is my try:

- file I/O

  - unbuffered I/O
  - buffered I/O

    - Standard I/O
    - formatted/unformatted I/O

is this correct ??

thx anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a good start.  I would add the following topics:

- asynchronous I/O: `epoll`, `poll` and `select`
- scatter/gather operations: `readv`, `writev`
- memory-mapped I/O: `mmap`